# How to save offline maps to SD card?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, storage, maps, micro-sd

I own a Nokia Lumia 620 which has 8GB internal memory and allows up to 64GB SD card.

The approx 6GB internal memory available are quite limiting to store a lot of offline maps.

Is it possible to have the Nokia Maps app store its maps on the SD card? ([I fear not](http://Forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/213933-save-offiline-nokia-map-file-sd-card.html), argl!)

Would installing the HERE app change anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I discovered there's an app in Nokia Beta Labs which lets you move maps to the SD card. It's called Storage Check:

http://betalabs.nokia.com/trials/Storage-Check

You just need to register your Nokia account and phone to the service. With this it should now be possible to offline as many maps as you want on your 620.

For anyone else, the app works with all Nokia WP8 Lumias with the Portico firmware update:

- Lumia 820 or Lumia 920: 1232.5957.1308.0000 and higher
- Lumia 920T: 2041.0009.1308.1002 and higher
- Lumia 520, Lumia 620 or Lumia 720: 1030.6407.1308.0000 and higher)

---

I'll add a quote:

> ### Lumia Storage Check - Beta (Likely to graduate to a commercial product.)
>
> Released: 18-04-2013
>
> Updated: 29-04-2013
>
> Lumia Storage Check Official version released as an update via Store,
>   but Beta 3 stays around.
>
> **We have just released the official version as an update via the
>   Store**. It has all the beta 3 features, **except the one to store Maps on
>   SD card.** The decision to omit this feature was made after a survey
>   sent out to many of you. A small, but still volume-wise significant
>   number of users would be having trouble with the feature and we want
>   to work on the SD card interface reliability a bit more before
>   considering the inclusion of this feature again.
>
> **As the official version lacks the Maps-on-SD-card feature, we are
>   going to keep the Beta 3 around** for you who want to use it or revert
>   back to using phone memory instead.

Comment: Looks promising. Shame that I've given my 620 away and switched to a Nokia 701.

Answer (score 3):

How much map data do you want offline? I just checked and Austria is 200MB (based on your profile I chose this one). The entire USA is 2.5GB. I have a 920, so no SD card to test with, but I am thinking you can't choose where to store them at this time.

Comment: Entire Europe (without Russia) is 5500MB on my Symbian SD card. The entire USA is only 2.5GB? That's quite surprising actually :-)

Comment: We have a lot of empty space, Europe is more dense I think.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to store App and Game data (I'd count maps as app data) on an SD card is rumored to be included in the coming Windows Phone 8.1 update:
http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-features

I'll update this answer once Windows Phone 8.1 is released to the public.

Comment: Map data can already be stored on SD cards as of the Lumia Black update (Storage check in settings).

Comment: @rikkit I don't see the appropriate option on my Lumia 620 with Lumia Black.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [information given by users on wpcentral](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/213933-save-offiline-nokia-map-file-sd-card.html), it is a current limitation of Windows Phone that no app related data whatsoever can be stored on SD card. (Not even PDFs or somesuch -- only music, pictures and videos.)

<sub>How pathetic. x-|</sub>